# Using Google Vision's detect_text on image with text in different directions

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-vision

So what I've recently discovered while playing with Google's Vision API for Python is that the method detect_text will only give me text aligned in a certain direction (probably decided by highest scoring text).  Is there a parameter or request variable I can set to tell it to give me all text regardless of direction?  There isn't much for documentation on anything, and the response parameters they show in walkthroughs don't match what is returned in the EntityAnnotation object I get back from the detect_text API call.